# Why don't we just take the root of the numerator instead of taking the root of the whole thing in the expression for standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation

The equation of the standard deviation of a dataset is given by $\sqrt{\frac{\sum{(x_{i} - \bar{x}})^2}{N}}$. Why is that the case and why can't we use $\frac{\sqrt{\sum{(x_{i} - \bar{x}})^2}}{N}$ instead? The units line up and we don't have to worry about negatives in this case too. Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the (sample) standard deviation that you give is derived from the formula for the variance. Let's first look at the definition of the variance. The variance of a random variable $X$ is defined as the expected squared deviation from the mean:
$$Var(X) = \mathbb{E}\left[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2\right].$$
Since this is an expectation (that is, a mean), it makes sense to estimate this by its sample version:
$$\hat{v} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i -\bar{x})^2,$$
that is, the sample average of the squared deviations from the sample average.

Now take a look at the definition of the standard deviation. The standard deviation is defined as
$$std(X) = \sqrt{Var(X)}.$$
Hence, it makes sense to estimate it by the square root of our estimator for the variance:
$$s = \sqrt{\hat{v}}.$$

That is,
$$s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i -\bar{x})^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks, but why is it that the definition of the standard deviation is chosen this way, how is it more useful than pulling the 1/N out before taking the root?

Comment: Because you are interested in estimating the square root of the variance, and the $1/N$ is part of how we estimate the variance, so we should include it in the square root.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you feel like the $1/N$ should be pulled out because then the equation would "look like an average" (i.e. we divide by $N$). But note that we did take an average when we consider the *variance*: the variance is just the *average of the squared deviations (from the mean)*. You take each value's deviation from the mean, square this deviation, then take the average of all of these squared deviations. This gives you the variance. But note that when we squared each deviation, we also "squared the units". To get back to the original units, we take the square root. This gives you the standard deviation.

Comment: With the way you've put it, it does makes a lot of sense. Thanks a ton for bothering to reply :)

Comment: Just a quick follow up, why is variance defined the way it is? Wouldn't it be better to define the variance exactly as per the alternate formula I've mentioned in the question instead of defining variance this way and then introducing a whole new quantity in standard deviation as it's square root?

Comment: There are many answers on this site about "why standard deviation" or "why variance" such as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118/why-square-the-difference-instead-of-taking-the-absolute-value-in-standard-devia). You can take a look at those.